# How can I run Minecraft in offline mode on OS X and still have my name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I'm trying to run Minecraft in offline mode on OS X while still setting my name to something other than "Player". I found some AppleScript written by Naschroe that may do the job:

```
property user_name : "Player"

display dialog "Enter A User Name" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2
set the user_name to text returned of the result

set UsrApp to (path to current user folder)
set UsrApp_unx to POSIX path of UsrApp

set MineScript to "java -cp " & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl_util.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/jinput.jar: -Djava.library.path=" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/natives -Xmx1024M -Xms512M net.minecraft.client.Minecraft '" & user_name & "'"

do shell script MineScript
```

But it needs some modifications to work and I can't seem to get it right. How can I modify this script to get Minecraft to work in offline mode, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but I'm guessing you need to change the text "(path to current user folder)" to something like "/Users/kpuffs" (or whatever your username is on your OSX machine is.)

Comment: Also, can you link the source for this script?  Did you get it from a forum thread or something similar?

Comment: I'm surprised that the script doesn't do a ~ expansion automatically. Also, please post a link to the source of the script. Oh! And do you have a shell script called `MineScript` on your Mac?

Comment: What is all this AppleScript doing that logging in with the wrong password won't do?

Comment: I do not see what you are asking. Before I upgraded to Lion, I could use Minecraft's offline mode on that version with that version of OS X.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If I'm correct, you should be able to play offline just by not entering correct credentials then clicking 'play offline'.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate? [How do you set Minecraft offline mode player name and also pass parameters into the jar?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53095/how-do-you-set-minecraft-offline-mode-player-name-and-also-pass-parameters-into) [Can Minecraft be played without being connected to the Internet?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/can-minecraft-be-played-without-being-connected-to-the-internet)

Answer (score 3):

Disconnect internet, open minecraft, and click on play offline. Then, if I were you, I would download and install LogmeinHamachi. Once you've set up a new network and invited your friends, you can go to your multiplayer in minecraft and add your ip address. Hamachi will act as something of a port, and enable you to easily host servers in offline mode.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with slightly smoother alternative to running that AppleScript - I used Automator to create an alternative launcher app that doesn't spawn a Terminal window. It was created on Mountain Lion but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work on previous Automator versions.

http://scumble.net/minecraft/MinecraftOfflineAutomatorApp.zip

This also works if you're using Forge to load mods - I discovered the above command causes the mod loader to crash. I make sure the shell is in the minecraft bin directory before starting up the client.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your WiFi. Turn on Minecraft. Try to log in. Now you should see something like this - bingo!

[image: BINGO]

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to add Minecraft to your firewall exceptions or try to login with a wrong username (ex. user: ABC pass: 123) and click "Play Offline" after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to log in offline if you use the wrong pass word it will ask if you want to log in offline or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try any number of things to go into offline mode.

- You could use an invalid username and password (ex. Username:password) then press "play offline". Note that this option will not work anymore since the launcher has been updated.
- The same solution as above would work if the launcher was not updated. Use an incorrect username and password or turning off your WiFi.
- The Alpha launcher (where you only need a username) would also work, but cheating is not recommended.