# How do you set Minecraft offline mode player name and also pass parameters into the jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to set the Minecraft offline mode player name via:

```
Java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*"
     -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives"  
      net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "MyName"
```

How do I pass more parameters to the Minecraft jar file? For instance, I would like to pass the directory parameter to the jar.

Also is it possible to make it so that the above line is executed through a Java applet?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: This article may help: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/9814-portable-minecraft-minecraft-on-your-usb-key. It discusses changing the directory.

Comment: why would you want to launch via applet? you already can do that at minecraft.net

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on StackOverflow or something of the sort? Like maybe SuperUser?

Answer (score 2):

> ***Disclaimer:*** I did write the tool I'm going to suggest to use. So, yes, this is shameless self-promotion. And no, this does not include any jars from Mojang, it is a stand-alone launcher-like...uuhhh...thingy...

You can do that with the [EasyMineLauncher](https://github.com/RobertZenz/EasyMineLauncher). It will allow you to set:

- The directory of the jars
- The minecraft.jar directly (which allows renaming of said jar)
- The directory of lwjgl
- The directory of the lwjgl native files
- The directory in which the `.minecraft` directory is stored
- A username
- Some window options
- A server and port to directly connect to

The following drawbacks are coming with that:

- No updates
- No authentication (not sure if you can play on Online servers which demand authentication or not)

You can check out the [Readme](https://github.com/RobertZenz/EasyMineLauncher/blob/master/README) for some further information.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a batch script that was originally for myself to put the .minecraft folder in the same directory as the launcher. I am not really sure what you are asking since your question is a bit vague. Assuming that minecraft is in C:\minecraft and that launch-minecraft.bat is in C:\minecraft, you can put this in launch-minecraft.bat to make .minecraft be in C:\minecraft:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D %~dp0
<your code here>
```

where `@ECHO OFF` is to make the display cleaner, `CD /D %~dp0` makes it so that it changes the working directory to where the batch script is located, and `<your code here>` is the code you want to use. Using this, your file structure should look like this (my ASCII art might be messed up on some systems):

C:
|_ Minecraft
....|_ launch-minecraft.bat
....|_ .minecraft