# How can I change the username on an online-mode enabled server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking for a batch command which allows you to change name on an "online-mode=false" Minecraft server.

I have tried these commands and lots of others:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft '"'%1'"'

@SET /P IGN=IGN=
@java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp "%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%/.minecraft/bin/natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft %IGN%
```

I'm running Mincraft via this command for now:

```
javaw -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -jar "C:\Users\Seras\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.exe"
```

I have Windows 7 x64 with Java 7 (build 1.7.0_02-b13, should be a 64-bit version).

Edit: I'm running the latest minecraft unmodded.
Btw found this "Client version 1.2.2 does not accept the command line arguments that previous versions accepted." so if anyone can get a command that works on a Client version 1.2.2 or later please post your command line here.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53095/8581 may help you.

Comment: Btw when I run:

Comment: java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -jar "C:\Users\Seras\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.exe" -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Seras\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "127.1"

Comment: It tries to connect to a server on 127.1 (localhost)

Comment: James; nah the thing is that I can't even run minecraft via that command... looking for a command that do the same thing and works on my system.

Comment: Yeah your original question asked about Offline mode.. there is no way to change the name of your character and connect to a server that does user validation

Comment: Yeah failed a bit; forgot to edit the "false" part after pasting it in... 

Anyway when running these commands i get Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can change your username (unless hacking or spoofing is involved - and I won't cover those) on `online-mode=true` servers.  The only way would be for the server you're connecting to to support commands (via mods) that are IRC-like which allow users to go by aliases.

Comment: Obs forgot to edit the true part :P it's an online-mode=false server. Fixed it in orginal post.